# Handling orientation change in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have been struggling with an issue in a note application i have been building with the help of a tutorial series. I just created a dialog allowing the user to change the category of a note but the new category is lost whenever the orientation is changed. as instructed by tutorial i override `onSavedInstance` to save information first but for some reason is not solved code below:

```
    package com.workingprogess.notebook;


    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class NoteEditFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageButton noteCatButton;
    private EditText title;
    private EditText message;
    private Button saveButton;
    private Note.Category savedButtonCategory;
    private AlertDialog categoryDialogObject;
    private AlertDialog confirmDialogObject;

    private static final String MODIFIED_CATEGORY="Modified Category";


    public NoteEditFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            savedButtonCategory = (Note.Category) savedInstanceState.get(MODIFIED_CATEGORY);
        }

        //grab layout and assign to view so that we may access widgets
        View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_edit, container, false);

        //grab widget references
        title = (EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteTitle);
        message = (EditText) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
        noteCatButton = (ImageButton) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.editNoteButton);
        saveButton = (Button) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.saveNoteButton);


        //populate with note data
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        title.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_TITLE_EXTRA));
        message.setText(intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.NOTE_MESSAGE_EXTRA));


        if(savedButtonCategory !=null){
            Log.d("not null","the new image should be carried over");
            noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(savedButtonCategory));
        } else {
            Note.Category noteCat = (Note.Category) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA);
            savedButtonCategory = noteCat;
            noteCatButton.setImageResource(Note.categoryToDrawable(noteCat));
            Log.e("null","pull from intent" );
        }


    //set onclick listeners
        buildCategoryDialog();
        noteCatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                categoryDialogObject.show();
            }
        });

        buildConfirmDialog();
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                confirmDialogObject.show();
            }
        });



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return fragmentLayout;
    }

    //save info before orientation change.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("save","info is saved");
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable(MODIFIED_CATEGORY, savedButtonCategory);
    }

    //build pop uo dialog to change note info
    private void buildCategoryDialog(){

        final String[] categories = new String[]{"Personal","Technical","Quote","Finance"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder  categoryBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        categoryBuilder.setTitle("Choose Note Type");

        categoryBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(categories, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {

                switch (item){
                    case 0:
                        savedButtonCategory= Note.Category.PERSONAL;
                        noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.p_icon);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        savedButtonCategory=Note.Category.TECHNICAL;
                        noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.t_icon);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        savedButtonCategory=Note.Category.QUOTE;
                        noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.q_icon);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        savedButtonCategory=Note.Category.FINANCE;
                        noteCatButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.f_icon );
                        break;

                }
                categoryDialogObject.cancel();

            }
        });

        categoryDialogObject=categoryBuilder.create();

    }

    private void buildConfirmDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        confirmBuilder.setTitle("are you sure?");
        confirmBuilder.setMessage("are you sure you want to save this note");

        confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Log.d("Save Note","Note title " + title.getText()+ "Note message "
                    + message.getText()+" note category" + savedButtonCategory);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                savedButtonCategory=Note.Category.TECHNICAL;
            }
        });

        confirmDialogObject = confirmBuilder.create();

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding (android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize") in the Activity -- Manifest file so it wont rerun the activity on orientation change  -- check here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your application **Manifest file** and for particular activity, add this code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" //Activity where the problem is occuring
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|orientation|screenSize">
```

Its better to add this "android:configChanges" to *every activity* to maintain data state even if orientation changes.

Comment: thanks a bunch! that solved my issue. i am very grateful was struggling for a while with that

Comment: Great it solved your problem. If possible, mark it as **accepted answer** so that people with similar problems can find it helpful and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if onSaveInstanceState is actually getting called? This callback will only be called if the Activity holding the fragment is getting destroyed. So, first check if your Activity is getting destroyed or not.

Comment: yes i used log to check that it was getting called three times each time the screen changed but adding "android:configChanges: to manifest solved the issue